# More effective way to change runtime terrain Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime, terrain

In my Unity game players are able to chop down trees using for example an axe. The tree then gets removed from the terrain and replaced by a falling tree prefab. This works fine in small scale. I am looking for a more effective way to do this though, because:

- The entire terrain needs to be reloaded if a tree is cut down. If the terrain is very large and complex this means that the entire game freezes for a few seconds whenever a tree is cut down.
- It works very poorly in multiplayer. In order for the terrain to stay in sync, all players terrain needs to be reloaded each time a tree is cut down. This means everyone's game freezes every few minutes.

I have thought about "chunking" the terrain but the entire terrain is already built and I don't know of a way to break it up into parts after it has been made.

Any ideas will be appreciated! I'm about an intermediate level programmer so I don't need anyone to write the code for me here, I just need an idea or suggestion as to the best way to do this?

Comment: Why does your terrain need to be reloaded when a tree is cut down?

Comment: In order for me to remove the tree from the terrain... The tree and collider needs to disappear from the terrain so I reload the terrain? Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Instead of using the built in unity trees, you could use your own trees! Get some tree prefab from the asset store and write a simple script to add them procedurally to your scene. Then you could update those trees without worrying about refreshing your terrain.

Comment: Excellent idea! I could add them all to an array then and manage it from that... If nothing else comes up I'll do that for sure, thanks!